# Do something if value is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I frequently find myself writing Ruby code where I check for the presence of a value and subsequently do something with that value if it is present. E.g.

```
if some_object.some_attribute.present?
  call_something(some_object.some_attribute)
end
```

I think it would be cool, if it could be written as

```
some_object.some_attribute.presence { |val| call_something(val) }
=> the return value of call_something
```

Anyone know if there's such a feature in Ruby or though activesupport?

I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21470) for this feature.

Comment: If you're just looking for a one-liner, you could use an inline if statement: `call_something(some_object.some_attribute) if some_object.some_attribute.present?`

Comment: This invokes `some_attribute` twice, which is not desirable for verbosity and performance reasons (if `some_attribute` invoked IO)

Comment: `attr = if some_object.some_attribute.present?
  call_something(attr)
end` this will call attribute only once

Comment: It's not necessary to say "Update". We can tell whether you've modified the question if necessary. Instead, simply add your additional information into the normal flow of the question.

Comment: You could also write `some_object.some_attribute.present & 
  call_something(some_object.some_attribute)`.

Comment: What's wrong with just `if object.attribute`? If it exists, it'll be true, if it's nil (aka not present) it'll be false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) and [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

> If `try` is called without arguments it yields the receiver to a given block unless it is `nil`:

```
'foo'.presence.try(&:upcase)
#=> "FOO"

' '.presence.try(&:upcase)
#=> nil

nil.presence.try(&:upcase)
#=> nil
```

Comment: I dislike `try` for various reasons, but here it is a great answer to the question.

Comment: Nice but only if you are on rails

Comment: Really cool - and it seems that you can omit `presence` and just invoke `try` directly.

Comment: Btw, I'm using Rails 4.1

Comment: @nsave, `try` is available by pulling in the appropriate Active Support core library, making it very lightweight and easily accessible in non-Rails code. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try

Comment: @NielsB. not really, in my second example `' '.try(&:upcase)` would execute the block and return its result, whereas `' '.presence.try(&:upcase)` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
do_thing(object.attribute) if object.attribute
```

This is usually fine, unless the attribute is a boolean. In which case it will not call if the value is false.

If your attribute can be false, use `.nil?` instead.

```
do_thing(object.attribute) unless object.attribute.nil?
```

Comment: I know, but I want to avoid referring `some_object.some_attribute` twice.

Comment: Unless the attribute is actually a method which is doing some heavy lifting, then there's very little overhead to calling it twice, it's a piece of data which is already stored in memory, so this is fast to execute.

Comment: You could set it to a local variable instead, although this really doesn't help much for only two useages. Or you could add the nil check inside your `call_something` method, keeping the calling code a bit cleaner. e.g. `def call_something(attr); return if attr.nil? ; #main body; end`

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no such functionality out of the box, one could do:

```
some_object.some_attribute.tap do |attr|
  attr.present? && call_smth(attr) 
end
```

On the other hand, Rails provides so many monkeypatches, that one could append one to this circus:

```
class Object
  def presense_with_rails
    raise 'Block required' unless block_given?
    yield self if self.present? # requires rails
  end
  def presense_without_rails
    raise 'Block required' unless block_given?
    skip = case self
           when NilClass, FalseClass then true
           when String, Array then empty?
           else false
           end
    yield self unless skip
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try instead. It's lightweight, it is well tested and supported. Years ago they broke Active Support into little chunks so we can cherry-pick what we want and can rely on the AS maintainers to keep it working.

Comment: @theTinMan `try` is a good choice, I just shew a technique that may be used. I upvoted Stefan’s answer, btw.